# Using Selenium with Python to fill out search-form

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Selenium and semi-new to python.  I'm trying to get Selenium to fill out a lengthy form.  The first part of that form consists of searching in a search bar to which a list automatically pops up. If a user sees what they are looking for, the user clicks the element in the list and that element shows up below the search bar (see pics below):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have tried the following code (or some form of the following code):

```
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
competitor = 'Bank of America Corp. (SNL P&C Group)'

comp_element = 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('<inputonkeydown="javascript:return 
disableEnterKey(event);" onkeypress="javascript:return 
disableEnterKey(event);" class="SNLTypeAheadSearchInput" type="text" 
id="searchInputOnetypeAhead" name="q" size="65" placeholder="Enter a company 
name, SNL group name, or NAIC #." onfocus=" var svc_url=&quot;&quot;; 
svc_url=&quot; 
/SNLWebPlatform/Content/UniversalSearch/UniversalSearchResponder. 
aspx? 
hasResults= 
False&amp;sets=-1&amp;maxResults=15&amp;additionalQuery=1,-1|-1,4,6&quot;; 
InitSearchField(svc_url, 0, true, false, 
SNLEntitySelectionTypeAhead_typeAhead.OnShowResultsFunction, 
SNLEntitySelectionTypeAhead_typeAhead.OnNoResultsFunction, 
SNLEntitySelectionTypeAhead_typeAhead.OnEnter, true, 
SNLEntitySelectionTypeAhead_typeAhead.OnHighlight, 
SNLEntitySelectionTypeAhead_typeAhead.OnNoHighlight, 
SNLEntitySelectionTypeAhead_typeAhead.OnGetActiveResultsEvent, 0, 
&quot;searchInputOnetypeAhead&quot;, 400, 
0);SNLEntitySelectionTypeAhead_typeAhead. 
AfterSearchInit(this,&quot;searchInputOnetypeAhead&quot;)"  
autocomplete="off" style="color: rgb(148, 148, 148);">')

comp_element.send_keys(competitor)

comp_element.click()
```

I get the following error:

`InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)`

I'm not sure why the selector does not work.  Truth be told, I'm not sure if I should be selecting this kind of element by css_selector.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a css selector, it looks like the entire inputs source - but luckily this means we can see other options to locate. Have you tried selecting by class name or id? Selenium offers several ways to find this input to send the specified keys.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

a css selector is more like this:

```
comp_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.SNLTypeAheadSearchInput')
```

or

```
comp_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchInputOnetypeAhead')
```

or you could just find element by class name:

```
comp_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('SNLTypeAheadSearchInput')
```

or by id:

```
comp_element = driver.find_element_by_id('searchInputOnetypeAhead')
```

Hope this helps!